# Sort by YES OR NO

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have search for Articles with dates. In MySQL is:

```
Article:
id | title
1  | first
2  | second
3  | third
4  | fourth
```

DatesArticle:

```
id | article_id | from       | to
1  |     1      | 10-10-2010 | 11-11-2010
2  |     2      | 11-10-2010 | 12-12-2010
3  |     1      | 13-12-2010 | 12-01-2012
4  |     3      | 11-11-2012 | 12-12-2012
5  |     4      | 02-02-2013 | 02-02-2014
```

i would like get all Article with dates and sort this by availability.

for example i would like get all Articles and SORT this by dates FROM 12-10-2011 TO 12-01-2012

this should return me:

1. first (is in range FROM TO - DatesArticle.id = 3)
2. third (is in range FROM TO - DatesArticle.id = 4)
3. second (is NOT in range FROM TO)
4. fourth (is NOT in range FROM TO)

Is this possible with SQL or SQL and PHP? If yes, how?

Comment: I don't get 3. and 4. can you display what do you expect?

Comment: i would like get all elements, but sort this element by availability

Answer (score 3):

Use the clause CASE, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM DatesArticle
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN id=3 AND CURRENT_DATE()<=from and to < CURRENT_DATE()>=to THEN 1
WHEN <condition_2> THEN 2
etc...
ELSE <any other condition>
END
```

Not saying the above is going to work as it is but it gives you and idea. If you add an example of the query you have tried or how are you building your where clause it would help for better answer.

Comment: thanks, +1, but i dont understand this answer for my problem :(

Comment: @PatrickSongerter: Not surprising.  I don't even understand the problem, so i imagine a bunch of people are just guessing here.  Perhaps you need to clarify the question/"spec" a bit more.

Comment: obviously needs a bit of work, but the idea is that your CASE clause assigns a order number to accomplish the way you want your data to be displayed.

Try to run the query below and you'll see what the case is supposed to do for you (I can't test this now but it should work):
`SELECT * FROM DatesArticle
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN id=3 AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()>=from AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()<= THEN 1 /* first availability */
WHEN id=4 AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()>=from AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()<= THEN 2 /* second availability */
ELSE 3
END`

Answer (score 1):

My idea was to when it's id= 3 assign 1, if id = 4 assign 2, any other value assign 3, after that make the where condition and order by the number that you assign.

Try this:

```
select *,  
      case when t1.id=3 then 1 when t1.id=4 then 2 else 3 end as t
from article as t1 
join DatesArticle as t2 
on t1.id=t2.id
where CURRENT_DATE()<=from 
and to < CURRENT_DATE()
order by t
```

Answer (score 1):

You must first JOIN the tables in order to access article's data.

Then you ORDER on a logical condition (if there's a date within the given range).

```
SELECT title
FROM Article JOIN DatesArticle
  ON (Article.id = DatesArticle.id)
  ORDER BY DatesArticle.from > LastDate AND DatesArticle.to < FirstDate DESC;
```

(I never get ASC and DESC right in logical sorts -- try and see what happens)

Comment: As for sort order, typically `false` comes first when you sort ascending.  Not only does it usually have an underlying value of 0, but it also comes first alphabetically.  :)  This probably doesn't apply if you have an `enum('y', 'n')` though.

Comment: OK, then the sort order was correct -- "inside=false" comes first when sorting ASC, we want it to come last, so we're sorting DESC. I have problems when considering clauses that aren't not negative, if you see my meaning :-)